# Bounding a sum of reciprocals of square-free integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, inequalities, square-free

*(Cross-posted from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4780595/help-bounding-sums-of-reciprocals-of-square-free-positive-integers), as the question did not get any clear answer)*

Fix positive integers $k$ and $n$. Let $N_1,\dots,N_r$ be all the integers less than or equal to $n$ that are squarefree and have exactly $2k$ distinct prime factors. Define $S = \sum_{j=1}^r \frac1{N_j}$.

For each $1\le j\le r$, choose a factorization $N_j = P_jQ_j$ into two numbers with exactly $k$ prime factors each, satisfying $Q_j > P_j$ (so that $P_j < \sqrt n$). These choices are certainly not unique.

By construction, it is straightforward that

$$S = \sum_{j=1}^r \frac1{P_jQ_j} > \sum_{j=1}^r \frac1{\sqrt n Q_j} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{j=1}^{r}\frac{1}{Q_{j}}.$$

Empirical trial and error leads me to conjecture that there exists a choice of factorizations such that
$$S\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{j=1}^{r}\frac{1}{P_{j}}.$$
However, I have not been able to prove it. Any hint or help would be welcomed. Thanks!

**EDIT**

I have a possible way to show something close to the conjecture (I have not been able to get anything better than what follows)

Choose every $P_j$ to be the minimum possible. Clearly, we can have $P_j=P_i$ for some or many $N_j$ and $N_i$.

Let us group those $P_j$ that are equal in subgroups with a subindex $k$, and their respective $Q_j$ in another subgroup with a subindex $k$, ordered by the value of the subindex $k$.

Let $s$ be the cardinality of a subgroup. We have that, conditionally to prove that $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^s \frac{1}{Q_k}}{s} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{N_s}}$, $$\sum_{k=1}^s \frac{1}{P_kQ_k} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{N_s}} \sum_{k=1}^s \frac{1}{P_k}$$
*Proof*

Multiply both sides of the inequality by $P_k$ to get that $$\sum_{k=1}^s \frac{1}{Q_k} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{N_s}}\cdot s$$ $$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^s \frac{1}{Q_k}}{s} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{N_s}}$$

This last inequality seems feasible to prove, but I have not been able to show it. If anyone could help with it it would be great.

If proved this, at the end we would have that $$S\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{N_{s_1}}}\frac{s_1}{P_{k_1}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{N_{s_2}}}\frac{s_2}{P_{k_2}}+\cdots $$ where $s_1+s_2+...=r$. Note that each $s_i$ can be replaced with the maximum $j\leq r$ such that $P_j=P_{k_i}$ divides $N_j$. And therefore, taking the minimum $N_{s_i}$ and denoting it as $N_f$, we would have that $$S \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{N_f}} \sum_{j=1}^r \frac{1}{P_j}$$ Note that $\sqrt{N_f} \sim \sqrt{n}$ as $n$ grows to infinity, so proving the conditional step would yield an interesting result.

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: @GHfromMO thanks for editing the tag!